# Syntax for C++ operator overloading in a class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, operator-overloading, friend

**Background**

I am self-learning C++ from [this course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/index.htm). I am trying to overload an operator in a class using a friend function [(Assignment 4.2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/assignments/MIT6_096IAP11_assn04.pdf)).

**EDIT**

The linked question does not answer my question. The accepted solution to that question gives a way for templates to be implemented in header + cpp file (not all in the same file).

In fact, I have consulted that question to partially come up with my situation.

**My attempt**

Using [Approach 2](https://web.mst.edu/%7Enmjxv3/articles/templates.html), I have **almost** gotten my code to work (see the cryptic error message). It turns out I am missing a `<>`.  ([Solution manual](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/assignments/MIT6_096IAP11_sol04.pdf)).

I have tried googling, but no-one else had the situations of

1. friend function,
2. operator overloading, and
3. in a templated class

simultaneously.

**My rationale**

You should not use a class public function to do operator overloading, because the object who calls the function will be implicitly passed, taking up one function parameter. It is better code-style to have the overloaded operator be symmetric (both in usage and in definition).

The usage of `friend` was suggested by the lecture notes.

**Question**

1. Why is `<>` needed?
2. Is there a better approach to doing operator overloading in a templated class?
3. (Optional) How can I make sense of the error message?

Thank you.

**Code**

stack.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::vector;

template <typename T>
class Stack;

template <typename T>
Stack<T> operator+(Stack<T> a, Stack<T> b);

template <typename T>
class Stack { // use default constructors and destructors
private:
    vector<T> s;
public:
    bool empty();
    void push(const T &item);
    T& top();
    void pop();
    friend Stack<T> operator+(Stack<T> a, Stack<T> b); // need operator+<>
};
```

stack.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
#include "stack.h"

template <typename T>
bool Stack<T>::empty() {
    return s.empty();
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T &item) {
    s.push_back(item);
}

template <typename T>
T& Stack<T>::top() {
    return s.back();
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::pop() {
    s.pop_back();
}

template <typename T>
Stack<T> operator+(Stack<T> a, Stack<T> b) {
    Stack<T> temp;
    while (!b.empty()) {
        temp.push(b.top()); 
        b.pop();
    }
    while (!a.empty()) {
        temp.push(a.top());
        a.pop();
    }
    Stack<T> c;
    while (!temp.empty()) {
        c.push(temp.top());
        temp.pop();
    }
    return c;
}

int main() {
    Stack<int> a, b;
    a.push(1);
    a.push(2);
    b.push(3);
    b.push(4);
    Stack<int> c = a + b;
    cout << c.top() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Error message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator+(Stack<int>, Stack<int>)", referenced from:
      _main in stack-d2f02a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Thanks for reopening. In general, to the people with power to close single-handedly, perhaps it would be nice to give question-askers some time to explain their case.

Comment: *"I have tried googling, but no-one else had the situations of"* - Thise person seems to have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989678/c-template-friend-operator-overloading

Comment: And since operators are really just functions with a funky name, this person seems to be asking the same thing you do, sans the operator minutia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803099/what-is-the-rationale-behind-the-syntax-chosen-to-declare-template-friends

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Next time, I will try one last google-search, before clicking "ask", because it becomes easier to google once I have a clearer, well-formed question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `<>` (or `<T>`) to make the friend declaration referring to the declared operator template. Without that the friend declaration would declare a non-template `operator+` which is not defined, that's why you got the linker error.

BTW: You can also specify the template argument explicitly like

```
// refers to the instantiation of template operator+ for T 
friend Stack<T> operator+<T>(Stack<T> a, Stack<T> b);
//                       ^^^
```

When using `<>` the template parameter `T` would be deduced from function parameter, and has the same effect.

```
// refers to the instantiation of template operator+ for T 
// T is deduced from function parameters
friend Stack<T> operator+<>(Stack<T> a, Stack<T> b);
//                       ^^
```

Comment: Okay! The ```<>``` is an implicit ```<T>```, which is needed to refer to the template. Curiously, if I also put ```<T>``` in the ```.cpp``` file, I get ```function template partial specialization is not allowed```. This is confusing. So I **only** need the ```<T>``` in the header file but not in the ```.cpp``` file. Why is this?

Comment: @BenjaminWang In the friend declaration, adding `<T>` means make the specialization for `T`, i.e. the `operator+<T>` friend. In `.cpp` file you're defining the template, then you shouldn't add that, just same as other function templates definition.